# How to scroll in appium (ios, real device) python a half screen

Tags: python, ios, appium

I have a problem, I have to scroll up through calendar, where every day has its own elements (and it may be added or deleted) and find some element for previous date.

All I  need - to scroll from here to some specific element (let assume that it is not duplicated).

I have tried with-

```
self.driver.execute_script("mobile: scroll", {"direction": "up"})
```

It works but sometimes it over scrolls and element will become invisible again

Ideal way is to have some method which scrolls from here to some element
Or to scroll not the whole screen, but only half of it.

I have tried the following:

```
self.driver.execute_script("mobile: scroll", {"direction": "up", 'element': el})
```

and

```
self.driver.execute_script("mobile: scrollTo", {"direction": "up", 'element': el.id})
```

but it doesn't work.

- Selenium (3.0.1)
- Appium (1.6.3)
- Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution. Maybe it will be helpful for someone:


For example, in my case it will be (scrollable is only left part of the screen)
< self.driver.swipe(window_size['width'] * 0.3, window_size['height'] * 0.15, window_size['width'] * 0.3, window_size['height'] * 0.65)>

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it works. Put a sleep after that works with your needs.

```
action = TouchAction(self.driver)
action.long_press(elementToTap).move_to(elementToDrag).release().perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you should use scroll without To
2. you will need 'toVisible' beside 'element' in the same dictionary
3. element ID is not the locator ID but it is the id within the session. can get it using `getId()` method

`self.driver.execute_script("mobile: scroll", {"direction": "up", 'element': el.id, 'toVisible' : 'any non empty text'})`

this should work with you